# Is there a way to implement typescript in a javascript project without renaming attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I am trying to implement typescript inside my javascript react project. But I am getting the error:
`JSX elements cannot have multiple attributes with the same name.  TS17001`

This is a snippet of my current code in js (.js file and not a .jsx file)

```js
<Col xs="12" sm="12" md="12" lg="12" xl="12">
  <Form className="form-horizontal">
    <Row>
      <Col xl="4" md={4} md="12">
        <label>Mode</label>
        <select
         className="custom-select ipt1"
         name="selectInputValue"
         value={this.state.selectInputValue}
         onChange={this.handleChange}
         defaultValue={this.state.queryFor}
        >
```

This is the error:

```
[react-scripts] JSX elements cannot have multiple attributes with the same name.  TS17001
[react-scripts]     255 | <Form className="form-horizontal">
[react-scripts]     256 |   <Row>
[react-scripts]   > 257 |     <Col xl="4" md={4} md="12">
[react-scripts]         |     ^
[react-scripts]     258 |       <label>Mode</label>
[react-scripts]     259 |       <select
[react-scripts]     260 |        className="custom-select ipt1"
```

I will have similar errors in pretty much every file of the codebase, what can I do to fix this problem and implement typescript in my codebase?

Comment: just wondering is there a reason for having md-{4} and md-12 ? im guessing for responsiveness?  it looks like those are conflicting and causing the error. maybe theres another way to make the column responsive

Comment: You can use - //@ts-ignore - above the md="12". But I also don't see a reason to have them both there. the latter will override the first one

Comment: May I ask you why would you need a duplicated prop name? The obvious answer to your question would be to fix the issue in all files where it occurs (after all, isn't that the reason for using a linter?). Alternatively you can set the linter in order to ignore that specific error, but I would advise against doing so.

Comment: As @secan pointed out, suppressing the error instead of fixing the root cause will very likely lead to more errors that "magically" happen. Also: JSX has nothing to do with typescript per se, and typescript files _do not_ have a filetype of `.jsx` - they have `.ts`. You are getting a warning/error from typescript because you use a typescript _linter_.

Comment: @secan The problem is there are thousands of props having this issue, fixing all of them would be a nightmare at this point, and suppressing it is leading to well lot more errors as David pointed out.

Comment: The props are probably getting overwritten by the most right value.